# Factor $\pi$ in thermal de Broglie wavelength

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

When writing down the thermal de Broglie wavelength
$$\lambda = \sqrt{\dfrac{2\pi\hbar^2}{mk_BT}}$$ one derives this with
$\lambda = \dfrac{h}{p}$, $E=\dfrac{p^2}{2m}$ and $E=\pi \cdot k_BT$.

What is the meaning of $\pi$ in the expression for the energy $E$?

Comment: Check out this question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201262/128428

Comment: $E = \pi k_b T$ is not correct in any sense I can think of. Where'd you get that? Also, note that you went from using $h$ in $\lambda = h/p$ to using $\hbar$ when you wrote $\sqrt{2\pi \hbar^2 / (m k_b T)}$. Since $\hbar \equiv h / 2\pi$ I think the real question you should be asking is why there's only *one* factor of $\pi$ under the square root instead of two.

Comment: I admit having been sloppy and just having checked on Wikipedia ("In the nonrelativistic case the effective kinetic energy of free particles is $\pi k_BT$") for the derivation of the wavelength.  The factor $\pi$ is probably hidden in the word "effective" there but that then is no explanation and doen't add any understanding. I suppose one just uses this definition of $\lambda$ to get rid of a factor of $\sqrt{\pi}$ in the (grand) canonical partition function for a non-relativistic dispersion $E=p^2/2m$.

Comment: I think this factor of $\sqrt{\pi}$ actually comes from the Maxwell-Botlzmann distribution of speeds, but so far when I try to recover the deBroglie wavelength starting from the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution I'm off by factors of 2.

Comment: Well, the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution of speeds can be derived from ensemble theory (canonical ensemble, non-relativistic particles in a potential). So the former is the more general case and the above definition of $\lambda$ does indeed get rid of a factor of $\sqrt{\pi}$ there.