# How energy $E= \pi k T$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

According to the Equipartition Theorem, $$E_{kin}= 3/2 k_B T$$ I read that when we are keeping the wave-nature of particles in mind, we can write $$E= \pi k_B T$$  But how we can write that?

Comment: Where did you read that? I don't recall hearing about that.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/201262/kinetic-energy-as-pi-k-b-t

Comment: You can obtain it by substituting $p = h  /\lambda_T$ into $E = p^2/2m$ but still it seems wrong. Maybe because I'm so used to the $3/2 k_B T$.